# Counting triangles with small intersection in a complete graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G=K_k$ be the complete graph on $k$ vertices.  Consider triangles (subgraphs induced by three vertices) which intersect pairwise in at most one vertex.  What is the maximum number of these that one can find, as a function of $k$. Please provide an explanation of your answer.

Comment: As many as you’d hope if the divisibility works out.  Namely, (n choose 2)/3 triangles.  These are called Steiner triple systems.  If the divisibility doesn’t work out, you can still get a ton of them in there.  See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.02909.pdf for an overkill thing.

Comment: @PatDevlin Thanks.

Comment: See also “triangle decomposition.”

Comment: In spite of the downvotes, the reference is extremely useful, so I am glad I asked the question